# Getting error: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0), why?

Tags: ios, swift3

My code is the following:

```
let mvc = MainViewController()
    let average = mvc.defaults.array(forKey: "grades") as! [Int]
    let averagePoints = mvc.defaults.integer(forKey: "averagePoints")
    gradePoints = averagePoints/average.count
```

At the last line, I get an EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) error. What does that mean and why do I get it?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: oups, I'm sorry, wanted to tag "application"

Comment: @Whazzup Put a breakpoint and print statements and test it once .

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if let average = mvc.defaults.array(forKey: "grades") as? [Int],
    let averagePoints = mvc.defaults.integer(forKey: "averagePoints") {
    gradePoints = averagePoints/average.count
}
```

Seems like the `grades` array or/and `averagePoints` is/are nil.